# How to connect to the database:mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs, gridfs-stream

Below is my code:The folder and filename is : `gridFs/storeAudio.js`.And the code is in `storeAudio.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
Grid.mongo=mongoose.mongo;


//establish mongoDB connection

var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/aHolyBoly');
conn.once('open',function(){
  //  var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
 // var db = new mongo.Db('aHolyBoly', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017));
//var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);

var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename:'song1.mp3'
});
fs.createReadStream('../list/hero.mp3').pipe(writeStream);
writeStream.on('close',function(file){
    console.log(file.filename +'Written to db');
});
});
```

now in the cmd inside the `gridFs` file I am running the command `node storeAudio.js` to create the database with the collection.But the following error is displayed below in the screenshot attached:
[image]

Note:I ran the following commands before:`npm install gridfs-stream`,`npm install mongoose`.

Please let me know if any more inputs are needed.

Comment: You are at least missing parentheses closing .once. Also, you have commented out the line where you are trying to define gfs.

Comment: cool.Thank you very much..although the problem is solved.but one line is still here while running the command `node sreamAudio.js` that is below:
`Deprecation Warning:Mongoose mpromise.................promises.html`What is the meaning of this line.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4291 Just add mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; before connecting.

Comment: Thank you so much  :) @Antti_M